# Create and store notes on mails

Tags: email, note-taking, synchronization, imap

I want to create notes on mails.

I use Thunderbird on PC and K9 on Android.

Notes created on one device should be visible on the other.

Which software can help me?

Comment: If you don't find a solution, try forwarding email to yourself - put your notes at the top and add "Note" to the title. If the not is not part of the email, I don't see how you can read it on other deceives, unless you find a very cross-platform app which synchs the notes and emails in some way.